# Convert C Code to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi

I need to convert this Line from C to Delphi.

```
Int CALLBACK EXPORT EXAMPLEFUNCTION(VOID){
  SETEVENT(hasync);
  Return Success;
}
```

Please i need some  help.

thanks ;)

Comment: there are a lot of automatic *.h to pascal converters. Just separate the definition from implementation; And implementation is trivial here.

Comment: @Arioch'The the problem with all those .h to Pascal converters is that they just convert the single .h, and not parse the includes and macros. So a lot of conversion ends up to be plain old handwork with a lot of educated guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of guessing here, because the style's really messy, but I think that would translate something like this:

```
const Success = 1; //or whatever; might not be 1.
                   //assume a const definition for a value 
                   //called Success exists somewhere in scope

function EXAMPLEFUNCTION(): integer; stdcall; //CALLBACK = stdcall calling convention
begin
   SETEVENT(hasync); //hopefully this makes sense in context
   result := Success;
end;
```

That's the best I can do without further context.  The `EXPORT` declaration is a preprocessor macro, and it (probably) means that this is part of a DLL and that this is a function that's supposed to be callable by programs that load the DLL.  In Delphi, that's not part of the function definition; instead, you put it in an **exports** clause.